# SSH to a windows server and run a command in that command server

Tags: perl, ssh, network-programming, cmd, network-protocols

so I have a set of commands that need to be run in a windows server 2003 (basically ant command to run eclipse-webdriver java code in cmd) . I want this commands to be run remotely using a click of button. So I setup a webpage in perl in that same server where the ant, webdriver is installed and same server where it should run the commands.

So a user can open the webpage in his personnel laptop and click on this button and the ant command should run in that remote windows server.

So how do I ssh(or connect) to that windows server from any of the devices (basically windows 7) ?

Is there a way in perl I can connect to that windows server ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different modules you can use for ssh, I like Net::OpenSSH, you could do something like:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('username@192.168.0.19',password  => 'pass');   
if ($ssh->error) {
  print "could not connect " . $ssh->error;
} else {
   # Run a command
   my @dir_files = $ssh->capture('dir C:\temp');
   if ($ssh->error) {
     print "command fail " . $ssh->error;
   } else {
      print "@dir_files"; # should have the results of the command
   }
}
```